# Unable to delete inherited file permissions in VB6 on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: com, vb6, windows-server-2012, adsi

I have a legacy VB6 COM application that I’ve recently had to migrate from a Windows 2008 R2 to a Windows 2012 R2 environment. The application works well apart from a section that strips the inherited permissions of certain (confidential) folders created on remote machines. The same code (below) works as expected on Windows 2008, however on Windows 2012 (using the same AD service account), will only delete permissions explicitly created on the folder in question. Does anyone know what has changed or what I’m doing wrong? I have noticed that the version of activeds.dll (C:\Windows\SysWOW64) has increased from 6.1.7601.17514 to 6.3.9600.17415.

```
Public Sub RemoveInheritedPermissions(ByVal sNTFSPath As String)

Dim sec As New ADsSecurityUtility
Dim sd As SecurityDescriptor
    Dim ace As New AccessControlEntry
    Dim dacl As Object

    Set sd = sec.GetSecurityDescriptor(sNTFSPath, ADS_PATH_FILE, ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID)
    Set dacl = sd.DiscretionaryAcl

For Each ace In dacl
            dacl.RemoveAce ace
    Next
    sd.DiscretionaryAcl = dacl
    sec.SetSecurityDescriptor sNTFSPath, ADS_PATH_FILE, sd, ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID

    Set sec = Nothing
    Set sd = Nothing
    Set dacl = Nothing
    Set ace = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.